# Recursive vector template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, operator-overloading

I've written the following piece of code:

```
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& v) {
    os << "{";
    for (auto i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i) {
        os << *i << " ";
    }
    os << "}";
    return os;
}
```

This works fine for regular `vector<int>` instances, but what I want to do is this:

```
vector<vector<int> > v={{1,2},{3,4}}
cout << v; // Should print {{1 2 } {3 4 } }
```

Instead, I get compilation errors (the following text, with a long list of candidates): `test.cpp|212|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >')|`

I'd have thought the templated function could be used twice, recursively. Am I wrong? If not, what gives? If so, is there some way to make this generic without duplicating code?

Comment: If you do not understand an error message, making a summary of it is not advised.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

 template<class T, class A>
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T,A>& v) {
     os << "{";
     for(auto&&e:v)
       os<<e<<" ";
     os << "}";
     return os;
 }

 int main(){
   std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3};
   std::cout<<v1<<"\n";
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2{{1},{2,3}};
   std::cout<<v2<<"\n";
 }
```

the above compiles and runs.  Fix your typos, or be careful what namespace you are working with.  Overloading operators in anything but the current namespace or in an ADL related one tends to fail.